# Image and audio feature extraction in Java

Tags: java, feature-extraction

I am looking for Java libraries that can be used to create feature vectors for a given image or audio file.

For example, if the input was 322.bmp the output would be something like

```
322.bmp 93.444 22.998 2.000 3.125 etc.
```

where each one of those numbers corresponds to an image feature such as coarseness, contrast, directionality and so on...

I tried using jAudio for the audio files but for some reason I couldn't get it to work. As for the images I didn't find anything relevant.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for C/C++ implementations and then attach them via JNI or translate them to Java.